Russian SU-57 vs US F-22s; who would win?
Let's say that Russia acquired a full squadron of SU-57s. Who would win? So they are flown by the same cloned person and have the same training. Both fighter squadrons have the exact same ground radar feed and absolutely no difference other than aircraft.

I think this is too much speculation, there's nothing concrete in this question. Su-57 vs F-22, where? when? how?

This is completely and solely opinion based.

It is not simply Su-57 vs F-22. You have to factor in pilot training, AWACS communication, etc, etc.
Regarding pilot training...If you put an average driver in a top line F1 or NASCAR car, and put him on the grid on Sunday, competing against pro drivers that train and practice every day...your "average driver" will come in dead last, or just dead. I'd wager that USAF and USN pilots get a LOT more relevant flight hours than Russian aircrew.
Regarding AWACS, which team has the better info? USAF/NATO AWACS can vector the fighters in from farther away than the Rus equivalent.
And the ceiling of the F-22 is not 50,000 feet. Witness the shooting of the Chinese balloon, which had the F-22 at 60k feet when it launched the missile.

Let's say that they are both flown by the same clone and have the same training and wits

@VFA-34 - And still, other factors come in to play. ROE, location, missile range, other things. Everything being equal except the airframe (and it NEVER is), I give the nod to the F-22, simply due to the better stealth. See and shoot before he knows you are there.
